# iPhone crash, ASIHTTPRequest or NSURL related

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, asihttprequest, crash-reports, cfrunloop

Given the following symbolicated crash log, is it more likely that the crash occurred due to the ASIHTTPRequest on Thread 5 or the NSURLConnection on Thread 3? I ask because this question has similar issues: [ASIHTTPRequest, EXC_BAD_ACCESS when request did finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164948/iphone-asihttprequest-exc-bad-access-when-request-did-finished)

However, they had more around their ASIHTTPREquest crash and it was on Thread 3 whereas my NSURLConnection is on Thread 3 with more info than the other.

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52c4 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd52b6 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33be9d72 abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bdba20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347c594 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31bd9f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3347b4c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  Foundation                      0x33639910 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 648
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33a767d6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
12  CoreFoundation                  0x33a485b0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
13  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47e54 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
14  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
15  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
16  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
17  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 GSEventRun + 56
18  UIKit                           0x32099322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
19  UIKit                           0x32096e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
20  AppName                         0x00002172 main (main.m:14)
21  AppName                         0x0000213c start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b89974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c33174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c32b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd724a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcf970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x304df124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x336465f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b8168c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33a7f662 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a57efe CFRunLoopRun + 42
6   StageBloc                       0x00032a08 +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4269)
7   Foundation                      0x33624192 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x3361d242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bd6886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x33bcba88 thread_start + 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a Three20 issue. When I initially installed it, I had to change some linker flags in the build settings. Those flags weren't changed for my distribution build, just my debug one. So the App Store people were seeing it crash because those necessary flags weren't there. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As other's have said, there's not enough information in the crash dump to tell if it's the NSURLConnection or the ASIHTTPRequest thread that might be involved, and the console output may help.

However, given past experience, it seems that the chances are that it involves ASIHTTPRequest.

What version of ASIHTTPRequest are you using?

The most common problem people have with ASIHTTPRequest is issues with request vs delegate lifetime, so I'd recommend double checking that in every object you have that can be a delegate to an ASIHTTPRequest (or an ASINetworkQueue) has in the dealloc method:

```
[request cancel]
[request setDelegate:nil];
[request release];
```

This should be done for **every** potentially active request.

Comment: I initially had it set up like this in my code. However, I've since gone to using more local variables as opposed to properties of the class. When the callback function gets called, I then clearDelegatesAndCancel at the end.

Comment: what if the callback is called after the delegate has been deallocated? You need to somehow make sure the request cannot outlive the delegate, as calling a deallocate delegate will almost certainly crash.

Answer (score 1):

Googled for objc_exception_throw __NSThreadPerformPerform and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698425/cocoa-touch-performselectoronmainthread-weird-behavior-crash) question with similar crash backtrace ... your exception might be the same missing selector thing. In that thread [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) suggests "going to your build settings and adding -Wundeclared-selector in the Other Warning Flags" to maybe catch this at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I've double checked that all of those are correct on my end.

Answer (score 0):

objc_exception_throw 8 or 9 down in the stack indicates, of course, an exception was thrown. you want to look in the device's console log (or xcode's run console if running in the simulator) to see if a message was logged before crashing.

(i have a bone to pick with os x & ios crash reporting, why aren't a bunch of the last lines logged to the console included in the crash report? that would be very helpful for a many kinds of crashes).

Comment: The thing is that there isn't any output to the console before the crash because I have personally never been able to make it happen. It only happens in some of the wizardy Apple does during their submission process. It's crashed for them three times now. Me or 10+ beta testers have never had it happen.

Comment: if it's apple reporting this crash to you, then they surely should know to provide you with the end of the console log as well as the crash log. i'd complain at them about this.

Comment: just filed a bug report asking for recent nslog output to be added to crash logs (radar id 9106728). been meaning to do that for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,
the problem is in Thread 5:

```
Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5d268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x33b5f354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a48648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33a57efe CFRunLoopRun + 42
**6   StageBloc                       0x00032a08 +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4269)**
```

ASIHTTPRequest could be the problem.
Try update the ASIHTTPRequest to the lasted version: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 0):

I used this as

```
[request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
request = nil;
```